# Change Nightmare visibility after initializing

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I was wondering how I can change Nightmare's visibility after the options object is set.

For example:

```
const Nightmare = require ('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare ({show: visible})
  .goto('https://google.com')
  .evaluate(function () {
   // Change nightmare visibility.
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, managed to figure it out. For those who have this question in the future, the solution is to replace

```
const Nightmare = require ('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare ({show: true})
  ...
  .evaluate(function () {
   // Change nightmare visibility.
  })
```

with

```
const Nightmare = require ('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare ({show: true})
   ...

nightmare.options.show = false;

nightmare.
   ...
```

This method can be used to change any of Nightmare's options mid execution.